# Swift 3 - No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'URL'

Tags: url, swift3

I just upgraded my swift project to swift 3 and i want to open url one of buttons onclick. Any help with little explanation would be appreciated.

The error says;

```
No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'URL'
```

Here is the code;

```
@IBAction func GPerformance(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let url = URL(string: "https://blablanet.blabla.gov.tr/analytics/saw.dll?Dashboard&NQUser="+USERNAME+"&NQPassword="+USERPASSWORD+"&portalPath=/shared/REPORT/_portal/PERFORMANCE&Page=WEEK%20Performance") {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Not sure about the issue here, but you should be generating this string programatically with something like `NSURLComponents`

Comment: My bad. Actually there is **+** operator before the **USERNAME** @Nirav D and it is not working.

Comment: @IbrahimBOLAT I have copy and paste your code in Xcode there is no error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = URL(string: String(format: "https://blablanet.blabla.gov.tr/analytics/saw.dll?Dashboard&NQUser=%@&NQPassword=%@&portalPath=/shared/REPORT/_portal/PERFORMANCE&Page=WEEK%20Performance",USERNAME!,USERPASSWORD!))
```

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

In Swift we can use string interpolation to add variables to are strings.
More can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292).

To use it wrapper the variable with a backslash and pair of parentheses inside the string.

So lets say

```
let myName = "Bob"

print("Hello my name is: \(myName)")
//Hello my name is: Bob
```

So your url should be

```
@IBAction func GPerformance(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://blablanet.blabla.gov.tr/analytics/saw.dll?Dashboard&NQUser=\(USERNAME)&NQPassword=\(USERPASSWORD)&portalPath=/shared/REPORT/_portal/PERFORMANCE&Page=WEEK%20Performance") {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```